# IForest spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to use scala implementation of IForest https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest, but when i build (like reported in README with `mvn clean package`), it give me these errors:

```
[ERROR] IsolationForest_Spark/spark-iforest/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/iforest/IForest.scala:290: 
        error: value getAndSetParams is not a member of object org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader
[ERROR]       DefaultParamsReader.getAndSetParams(model, metadata)
[ERROR]                           ^
[ERROR] IsolationForest_Spark/spark-iforest/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/iforest/IForest.scala:480:
        error: value create is not a member of object org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation
[ERROR]     val instr = Instrumentation.create(this, rddPerTree)
```

Does someone knows why?
Thank you

scala version 2.11.12 
spark version 2.4.0 
maven version 3.5.2

I modified pom.xml adjusting version of scala, spark and maven, but I leave the same dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just upgraded spark-iforest to the latest spark version.

https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest

Have Fun ;)

Answer (score 2):

*The project has been updated since this answer was written see F.Z.Yang's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53941452/1900169).*

The spark iforest is using a spark internal api `getAndSetParams` which was moved in spark 2.4.0 according to [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/83013752e3cfcbc3edeef249439ac20b143eeabc) and [issue SPARK-23455](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23455).

It seems spark iforest was [compiled with spark 2.2.0](https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest/blob/14b659e72ca84fa2d6ea540d5c617c31d63afe21/pom.xml#L21), so you should probably start with that version.

You could try the pervious version (2.3.2) but if there are other breaking changes that may not work either.